# undefined method `each' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, for-loop, nomethoderror

I'm writing a for loop in Ruby that iterates through the elements of an array until there are not more elements to read or a condition is met. This is my implementation:

```rb
# 'all' is an array

exists = false

for i in all && !exists
  exists = all[i].has_card
end
```

As the title says, I'm getting this runtime error:

```
undefined method `each' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)
```

I'm fairly new to Ruby, but I'm guessing the problem is that the `for` loop is trying to iterate over both `all` and `!exists` which is `true`. How can I write a for that works the way I want?

EDIT: If it serves as clarification, this is how I would implement it in C++:

```cpp
for (int i=0; i<all.size() && !exists; i++) { /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, eww. `for` is never used; it's the "moist" of Ruby. :)

`for item in items ... end` is executed by Ruby as if you wrote `items.each do |item| ... end`. (That's actually how Rubyists would write it in the first place.) This is relevant; so hang on.

Your line parses as:

```
for i in (all && (!exists))
```

When `exists` is `false`, `!exists` is `true`. Now, the `&&` operator will check if the first argument is truthy; if it is not, it returns it; if it is, it returns the second argument. Since `all` is presumably truthy, `all && true` returns the second argument — true.

Now remember that your line actually, in the background, calls the `each` method on the collection you are iterating. And your "collection" is `true` — not a collection at all. You can't iterate on `true`.

If you don't want to use `break` (which is somewhat unreasonable, and you can quote me), you can use other methods from the `Enumerable` module. For example:

```
all.take_while { |item| !item.has_card }.each do |item|
  # ...
end
```

This is a bit slower than the `break` method, since it will construct an intermediary array containing only the first N items that don't have cards that it will later iterate on, but worrying about it is a premature optimisation.

EDIT: Unfortunately Sebastian deleted their answer, which had the correct idiom (the one I would probably write sooner than the one above, though it definitely depends on the case), so I repeat it here:

```
all.each do |item|
  break if item.has_card
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Nope. `for` (and equivalently `each` will _only iterate on the whole collection_. There is no way for you to specify an additional condition. You do that using functions other than _each_, or by using `break` conditionally. There is no way to do what you want purely using `for`. Ruby `for` has almost nothing to do with C `for`, and it would be better for you to forget it exists.